# Can't finish the do-while loop by pressing enter key

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I want to finish my do-while loop when I pressed the enter key. Do you have any idea to solve this problem? I tried to check ASCII code for ENTER key but it didn't work out.

```
                  do{
                    for(int dongu=0;dongu<secimSayi;dongu++)
                    {
                        cout<<"-";
                        sleep(1);
                        if(dongu==secimSayi-1)
                        {
                            cout<<">"<<endl;
                        }
                    }
                    for(int dongu2=0;dongu2<secimSayi;dongu2++)
                    {
                        cout<<" ";
                    }

                    for(int dongu3=secimSayi;0<dongu3;dongu3--)
                    {

                        cout<<"-\b\b";
                        sleep(1);                               
                        if(dongu3==1)
                        {
                            cout<<"<"<<endl;

                        } 
                    }

                }while(getchar()== '\n');  //I want to end this do-while loop when I pressed ENTER
```

Comment: I don't see any code here that attempts to exit the loop when enter is pressed.

Comment: You might need to read the input by using `cin` for example.

Comment: (1) Don't spam tags. C and C++ are different. (2) Post a proper example, as suggested in the help center of this site.

Comment: C++ I/O is blocking by default, meaning that if you when you allow user input you will have to wait on the user to press enter. Getting around this with just the standard library will not be easy. Since this site doesn't allow for the request of third party library suggestions mybe a better plan would be to talk about what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe that there is a standard solution for this in C++ and that is normally not the way standard console programs work.

the most standard way could be using [threads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread), where one thread waits until a line is read and then signals that to main thread by setting an `std::atomic<bool>`.
(See example)

Another solution could be to look for the right library according to operating system.  On linux, you could use [ncurses](http://hughm.cs.ukzn.ac.za/~murrellh/os/notes/ncurses.html), on windows, there is also [support](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7x2hy4cx.aspx).  This should also give more control over the output of the program.

Example for the threaded approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <atomic>

class WaitForEnter
{
public:
  WaitForEnter() : finish(false)
  {
    thr = std::thread([this]() { 
        std::string in; 
        std::getline(std::cin, in);
        finish = true; 
      });
  }
  ~WaitForEnter()
  {
    thr.join();
  }
  bool isFinished() const { return finish; }
private:
  std::atomic<bool> finish;
  std::thread thr;
};

int main()
{
    WaitForEnter wait;
    while (! wait.isFinished())
    {
      std::cout << "." << std::flush;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
    std::cout << "\nfinished\n";
}
```

Comment: I think there is, but you need to code for all operating systems, for example OpenNI have [xnOSWasKeyboardHit](https://github.com/OpenNI/OpenNI/blob/master/Source/OpenNI/Linux/LinuxKeyboard.cpp), so you can use `while(!xnOSWasKeyboardHit()) { code... }`

Comment: @cpatricio: I don't know it, but still it is a library instead of using standard c++.  The link points to linux-keyboard.  Are you sure it is os independent?  Anyway, if you think this is a better solution, feel free to make your own answer.

Comment: @cpatricio: after having another look, termios.h from opengroup is rather standard, but not standard c++ (it is not supported on windows).  But it is a good way to provide polling based input.